# WPF: How can I wrap a content control in another?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have the following as the body of a `UserControl`:

```
<Label FontWeight="Bold"
       x:Name="PaletteLabel"
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
       BorderThickness="1"
       >
    <Label.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                             StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFB6B5C3"
                          Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF4F4F6"
                          Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Label.Background>
    <ContentPresenter  />
</Label>
```

I expect to be able to use it like this:

```
<uc:NiceLabel>Text Content</uc:NiceLabel>
```

But that does not give me the effect I expect. Am I making any obvious mistakes here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a simple style (if I'm getting you correctly).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="NiceLabelStyle">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                             StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFB6B5C3"
                          Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF4F4F6"
                          Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Style="{StaticResource NiceLabelStyle}">Test</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly covered in [How to create a WPF UserControl with NAMED content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751325/how-to-create-a-wpf-usercontrol-with-named-content)