# How to refer to another XAML element inside a custom nested user control?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I want to refer to another element, which resides as nested under a custom user control:

```
<userControls:Test>
     <TextBox Name="Foo" />

     <Button CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=Foo" Command="{Binding anything}" />
</userControls:Test>
```

Basically I'm using commands and I'm trying to refer to another element with a name, but I get this famous:

> Cannot set Name attribute value '...' on element '...'. '...' is under
>   the scope of element '...', which already had a name registered when
>   it was defined in another scope.

I figured it's impossible to name an element: [How to create a WPF UserControl with NAMED content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751325/how-to-create-a-wpf-usercontrol-with-named-content)

So is there any *other* way to refer to the element that would work inside nested custom user control content?

Comment: In xaml you should not use x:Name instead of just Name? I know it's not the answer...

Comment: Can you show some code, including the actual trimmed-down version of the XAML it operates on?

Comment: The code above works ok for me with a UserControl.  Can you give more details, do you mean custom control, or user control?  Also I assume there should be a closing } in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.FooBar"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:MyProject.UserControls"
         Loaded="Loaded"> <!-- notice -->

    <userControls:Test>
         <TextBox Initialized="FooInitialized" />

         <Button Initialized="AnotherInitialized" />
    </userControls:Test>
```

And code:

```
// This for every initialization, all we do is set names after the elements are initialized.
private void FooInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox) sender).Name = "Foo";
}

// Here when the entire junk is loaded, we set the necessary commands.
private void Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Find elements.
    var button = UIHelper.FindChild<Button>(this, "Bar");
    var textBox = UIHelper.FindChild<TextBox>(this, "Foo");

    // Set up bindings for button.
    button.Command = ((FooViewModel) DataContext).FooCommand;
    button.CommandParameter = textBox;
}
```

The `UIHelper` is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/283055. The button is also given a name the same way as the text box.

Basically all names are set via `Initialized` event. The only down side is that you must refer to the names in code, and that's why I'm setting commands via code after the entire component has loaded. I found this the best compromise between code and UI markup.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a reasonable workaround. In your view bind the Text to FooText property on the viewmodel, directly beside the declaration of the ICommand. When the command executes, use the latest FooText

```
<!-- View -->
<userControls:Test>
     <TextBox Text={Binding FooText, Mode=TwoWay} />

     <Button Command="{Binding FooCommand}" />
</userControls:Test>


// ViewModel
public string FooText { get; set; }

public ICommand FooCommand 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return new DelegateCommand(() => ExecuteFoo(FooText)); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a template to the UserControl.

```
<....Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" x:Key="MyUserControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_Foo"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=PART_Foo, Path=Text}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter  Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},Path=Content}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</....Resources>
<UserControl Style="{StaticResource MyUserControl}">
</UserControl>
```

Then name the template with a key, and specify which UserControl uses which template.

Also, in your code, you could get the PART_Name of the templated part using:

```
UIElement GetUserControlPart(UserControl control, String name)
{
   return control.Template.FindName(name, control) as UIElement;
}
```

Comment: How would this work if I used custom properties like `<userControls:Panel.Header>...</userControls:Panel.Header>`? Because right now with this approach it renders the text `"System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate"`.

Comment: After removing the `ControlTemplate` it seems to work in VS preview mode but throws about unable to cast `TextBox` into a `DockPanel` (add it to a collection of dock panels).

Answer (score 0):

If you use .NET 4.0 and require to set the binding source to the sibling control, then you could use this MarkupExtension:

```
public class SiblingSourceBinding : MarkupExtension
{  
    public Binding Binding
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int SiblingIndex
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var provideValueTarget = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;

        if (provideValueTarget != null)
            this.Binding.Source = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(provideValueTarget.TargetObject as DependencyObject)).Cast<object>().ElementAt(this.SiblingIndex);
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to set sibling binding source.");

        return this.Binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
   }
```

and use it like this:

```
<userControls:Test>
    <TextBox/>
    <Button CommandParameter="{local:SiblingSourceBinding Binding={Binding Text}, SiblingIndex=0}" Command="{Binding anything}"/>
</userControls:Test>
```

Comment: You could change it to ElementName by searching for name?

Comment: ElementName cannot be specified in this case, that was the original problem.

Comment: Is there any other way to "mark" the text box with any sort of identifier that could be used? In this scenario a sibling works but if the structure is more complex the issue remains.

Comment: Perhaps Tag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) property could be used. Then a search through logical (or maybe visual?) tree would have to be performed to find a FrameworkElement with specific Tag value. I am assuming the element would have to be defined in XAML before text-box, because otherwise it wouldn't be a part of a logical tree when MarkupExtension.ProvideValue is called (current solution also has this issue).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Uid in your nested element as in the following:

```
<userControls:Test Name="usrCtrl">
     <TextBox Uid="Foo" />
     <Button Uid="btn"/>
</userControls:Test>
```

Then you use the following function (the function was a solution for this answer [Get object by its Uid in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887611/get-object-by-its-uid-in-wpf)):

```
private static UIElement FindUid(this DependencyObject parent, string uid)
{
    var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    if (count == 0) return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var el = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i) as UIElement;
        if (el == null) continue;

        if (el.Uid == uid) return el;

        el = el.FindUid(uid);
        if (el != null) return el;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then in your Loaded function add this:

```
private void Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Find elements.
    var button = FindUid(usrCtrl, "btn") as Button;
    var textBox = FindUid(usrCtrl, "Foo") as TextBox;
     
    // Do binding here...
}
```