# How to access Storyboard in Windows 8.1 (WinRT)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

In my xaml file I have:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"...>
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="WebformSizeState">
<VisualState x:Name="MaximizedSizeState">
     <Storyboard x:Name="MaximizeSizeStory">
         <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="-120" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="WebpageContainer"/>
     </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
...

<ec:DataTriggerBehavior Value="2" Binding="{Binding WebpageSizeState, Converter={StaticResource EnumToIntegerConverter}}">
     <ec:GoToStateAction StateName="MaximizedSizeState"/>
</ec:DataTriggerBehavior>
...
```

The code works, as is. If the `WebpageSizeState` get the in value of `2` then the `WebpageContainer` moves up by 120.

**I want to change `To` value of the `DoubleAnimation` of the Storyboard in the code behind file programmatically, but to do this I need to get the Storyboard (I assume).**

### Things I tried but failed:

#### Attempt 1

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.aspx), direct access should work, but if I try to assign the value:

```
Storyboard maximizeSizeStory = MaximizeSizeStory;
```

then maximizeSizeStory is `null` and looking in the *Watch* window, `MaximizeSizeStory` is also null.

#### Attempt 2

Assigning a name to the `DoubleAnimation` and trying to access it directly:

```
<DoubleAnimation x:Name="MaximizeAnimation" ../>
```

This causes the app to crash with a null ref exception when the DataTrigger binding is changed in the ViewModel.

And oh yeah, the value in the code behind is `null` also.

#### Attempt 3

Finding the element using it's `UID` as done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887611/get-object-by-its-uid-in-wpf):
You cannot because [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.aspx) and [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.aspx) does not define a UID anymore.

And [Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard.aspx) isn't a UIElement, which I think is the reason why using `FindName`

```
Storyboard sb = this.FindName("MaximizeSizeStory") as Storyboard;
```

also returns null.

#### Attempt 4

Accessing it via a `Key` does not work because it's not defined in `Page.Resources` or in a dictionary.

And if you try do declare it in `Page.Resources` it gives error:

> A property element cannot be the direct content of another property element.
> Nested properties are not supported: VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups.

---

I'm at a loss, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way (simplified example for clarity). Notice the use of the **VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups** since the Storyboard is inside it:

[image]

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyGroups">
                <VisualState x:Name="MyStates">
                    <Storyboard x:Name="MyAnimation">
                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Yellow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
             </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Height="50" Width="50" Fill="red"/>
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Click me"                Click="Button_Click" />    
</Grid>
```

And code for the button handler, where we actually access the storyboard:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var storyboard = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this.LayoutRoot)[0].States[0].Storyboard;
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Adding some extensions could make the code more readable and less prone to errors:

```
public sealed partial class SomePage
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        var storyboard = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this.LayoutRoot).Get("MyGroups").States.Get("MyStates").Storyboard;
    }
}

public static class StateExtensions
{
    public static VisualStateGroup Get(this IList<VisualStateGroup> stateGroups, string name)
    {
        return stateGroups.Single(x => x.Name == name);
    }

    public static VisualState Get(this IList<VisualState> stateGroups, string name)
    {
        return stateGroups.Single(x => x.Name == name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! However, I think the line should be: `var storyboard = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this.LayoutRoot).Get("MyGroups").States.Get("MyStates").Storyboard;`

Comment: Ops hehe, will change :)