# WPF UserControl with DataGrid, adding extra columns in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, user-controls

I am trying to reuse the XAML that I am writing as much as possible.

Now, I would like to display my objects in DataGrids. My objects share some common properties through heritage. Therefore I would like to create a UserControl with a grid and among others define some columns for the properties that are common to each objects. So something looking like that:

```
<UserControl Name="MyCustomGrid">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid>
            <!-- Common Settings -->
                ...
            <!-- /Common Settings -->
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <ADataGridColumn Name="CommonProperty1"/>   
                <ADataGridColumn Name="CommonProperty2"/>
                ...
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then I would like to be able to use this UserControl and add **extra** columns for the specific properties of the objects I want to display, **through XAML** like so:

```
<view:myCustomGrid>
   <view:myCustomGrid.Columns>
       <ADataGridColumn Name="SpecificProperty1"/>
       <ADataGridColumn Name="SpecificProperty2"/>
       ...
   </view:myCustomGrid.Columns>
</view:myCustomGrid>
```

Is this possible ? I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758342/how-to-create-wpf-usercontrol-which-contains-placeholders-for-later-usage) question but it doesn't seem like I can insert an ContentControl under DataGrid.Columns

Maybe this is not the way to go...

Thanks for your help

Comment: showing simple additional columns may be easy but later on you probably need ranges, constraints and validations and that will be endless work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define columns like this; including different types

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn/>
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn/>
        <DataGridTextColumn/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When you set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` which is the default you will get the columns from your bound properties as well. If you only want to see the specified columns you have to set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`.

The `DataGridTemplateColumn` is for userspecific columns. So you can put everything you want in it.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--Content-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--Content-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But why do you want to encapsulate this in a `UserControl` instead of doing it for the `DataGrid` instances itself? I would suggest specify the columns for each `DataGrid` because it would be a a lot of work putting this into a `UserControl`. Or using styles when you have some things which are the same for each `DataGrid`.

Comment: i think the OP's concern is 'add columns at runtime', and currently he does not care about column types.

Comment: @mighty-badaboom I know about the different column types. The thing is that I have 3 grids quite similar and that I have to make the modifications 3 times on common settings (and not just style). Auto generating doesn't seem ideal because I have custom columns and I want my columns in a certain order. What I had in mind doesn't seem possible just like that. I will use templates as much as I can, so that the DataGrids' XAML stays, as concise as possible. Thanks