# <view:Content ...> tags in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, view

I inherited some code where I've seen this construction, which I'm not used to, in several locations:

```
    <view:Content x:Name="TimeFrame" Margin="220,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <view:Content.ChildContent>
            <view:TimeFrame />
        </view:Content.ChildContent>
    </view:Content>
```

Which I must admit seems rather nifty, and thus far works as I want it too. However, then there's this where instead of the `<view:TimeFrame />`-tag in the center there are a regular control-tags like so:

```
    <view:Content x:Name="SignInControl" Margin="466,317,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="348" Height="344" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <view:Content.ChildContent>
            <Grid>
                <Border  CornerRadius="8,8,0,0" BorderThickness="1" Width="270" Height="300" Background="#666666" Margin="1,0,-1,0" Opacity="0.57"  >
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <BlurEffect/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                </Border>
                <Border  CornerRadius="8,8,0,0" BorderThickness="1" Width="270" Height="300" Background="#FFF3F5F4">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="ChartWizz" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="10" Margin="0,3,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource up_down}" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" />
                        <Image Source="Pictures/logo_250.png" Margin="5"  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <StackPanel Width="210" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <TextBlock Text="Change User or"  Margin="0,0,3,0" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="11" />
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Click="CreateNewAccLink_Click" Margin="2, 0, 0, 0">
                                <TextBlock Text="Create new account" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="11" Foreground="Black"   TextDecorations="Underline"/>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <TextBlock  Text="Username" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="10" Margin="0,0,0,3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBox Width="210" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <TextBlock  Text="Password" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="10" Margin="0,4,0,3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <PasswordBox Width="210" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Click="ForgotPassLink_Click" Margin="2, 0, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock  Text="Forgot your password?"  Width="Auto" Foreground="Black" TextDecorations="Underline" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="10" Margin="27,5,0,3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="7" Width="210" Margin="0,5,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <CheckBox  Content="Remember me" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="10" Margin="0,4,0,3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Button Width="60" Content="Sign in" Height="23" Margin="55,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="SiginBtn_Click" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </view:Content.ChildContent>
    </view:Content>
```

When I attempted to give the controls here names so that I could access them in code I got the following error:

> Cannot set Name attribute value 'txtBox_username' on element 'TextBox'. 'TextBox' is under the scope of element 'Content', which already had a name registered when it was defined in another scope.

I don't know if it's possible to access these members in some other way through the Content scope but if anyone would enlighten me I would be grateful. Either way I'd really like a link to a relevant MSDN page(or other resource) as I can't seem to figure out what to search for in order to learn more about  type tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by how `UserControls` are implemented, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751325/how-to-create-a-wpf-usercontrol-with-named-content) for workarounds.

Comment: Haven't looked into it quite yet, but the info given in that question seems to do the trick at first glance at least. Thanks!