# How to use targetname with usercontrol and trigger

Tags: c#, php, javascript, wpf

I made UserControl of DataGrid. I placed this new component into page1.xaml. I would like to use some template and setting based on value in Data1.

Could you help me with this code how to avoid the error message?

```
<my:MyDataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,295,0,0" Name="myDataGrid1" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="151" Width="176" SelectionChanged="myDataGrid1_SelectionChanged">
        <my:MyDataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Col1" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data1}" x:Name="mytext" />
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data1}" Value="1">
                                <Setter TargetName="mytext"  Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </my:MyDataGrid.Columns>
    </my:MyDataGrid>
```

I got error message:

> Cannot set Name attribute value 'mytext' on element 'TextBlock'.
>   'TextBlock' is under the scope of element 'MyDataGrid', which already
>   had a name registered when it was defined in another scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a WPF UserControl with NAMED content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751325/how-to-create-a-wpf-usercontrol-with-named-content)

Answer (score 0):

You can add you data trigger to a style attached to a TextBlock

```
<my:MyDataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ...>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Col1" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data1}" x:Name="mytext">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data1}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</my:MyDataGrid>
```