# custom layout in WPF that works with Blend?

Tags: wpf, blend

in my project we have a reoccurring dialog layout that i'm hoping to consistently replicate between each of the similar dialogs.

In the template dialog, we have a grid that contains a logo and in the center of the dialog has controls specific to that particular instance of the dialog

my hope is to somehow consistently replicate the look, like a template, across each of the dialogs.

- I think I want a layout control, where content can be added to the center of the grid
- I want to use Blend,  such that our designers can manipulate the controls specific to the individual dialog while looking at the template

is there a way to do this?  I'm I looking in the wrong direction by thinking of a custom layout control?  would I be better off with some type of grid template?

Comment: You can do this with a simple `ContentControl`, by setting it's `ContentTemplate` to the "templated" part of the Dialog, and leaving a `ContentPresenter` as a placeholder for the modifiable part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great way to do this - [How to create a WPF UserControl with NAMED content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751325/how-to-create-a-wpf-usercontrol-with-named-content)

my preferred is not the answer to the above question, rather the comment

"The answer is to not use a UserControl to do it.

Create a class that extends ContentControl"