# Unable to set Name property of child controls on UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a *UserControl*. It contains several elements of specific style and have a *DockPanel* to contain children which added later on *MainWindow.xaml*.
It works properly and can have it's children on *MainWindow.xaml*. But when you set *Name* property on the any of children, It produces 'the name is aleady used' exception on compiling.
What do I have to think more about? Without setting *Name* property, it works properly.

> Exception: Cannot set Name attribute value 'ThisProduceAnError' on element 'TextBlock'. 'TextBlock' is under the scope of element 'PropertyPanel', which already had a name registered when it was defined in another scope.

**UserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TrainingWpf1.PropertyPanel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TrainingWpf1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="120" d:DesignWidth="260">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Title"/>
        <Border Padding="10" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="6" Background="CadetBlue">
            <DockPanel x:Name="panContent" />
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace TrainingWpf1
{
        [ContentProperty(nameof(Children))]
        public partial class PropertyPanel : UserControl
        {
                public PropertyPanel()
                {
                        InitializeComponent();
                        this.Children = panContent.Children;
                }

        public UIElementCollection Children
        {
                get => (UIElementCollection)GetValue(ChildrenProperty.DependencyProperty);
                private set => SetValue(ChildrenProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ChildrenProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
                nameof(Children),
                typeof(UIElementCollection),
                typeof(PropertyPanel),
                new PropertyMetadata());
        }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TrainingWpf1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TrainingWpf1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">
        <Grid>
                <local:PropertyPanel>
                        <TextBlock Name="ThisProduceAnError" Text="Hello"/>
                </local:PropertyPanel>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Could yo please add the whole exception?

Comment: I added the whole exception on the post.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751325/how-to-create-a-wpf-usercontrol-with-named-content

Comment: In my original code, it has other stuffs such as folding button, events, handlers, etc. I don't know how to handle those things with only a ContentControl and it's style templete.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use XAML:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TrainingWpf1
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Children))]
    public partial class PropertyPanel : UserControl
    {

        public PropertyPanel()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            DockPanel panContent = new DockPanel();
            this.Children = panContent.Children;
            Border border = new Border()
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(10),
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
                CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(6),
                Background = Brushes.CadetBlue,
                Child = panContent
            };

            DockPanel dockPanel = new DockPanel();
            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock() { Text = "Title" };
            textBlock.SetValue(DockPanel.DockProperty, Dock.Top);
            dockPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
            dockPanel.Children.Add(border);
            Content = dockPanel;
        }

        public UIElementCollection Children
        {
            get => (UIElementCollection)GetValue(ChildrenProperty.DependencyProperty);
            private set => SetValue(ChildrenProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ChildrenProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
                nameof(Children),
                typeof(UIElementCollection),
                typeof(PropertyPanel),
                new PropertyMetadata());
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok. It works now with your solution. Thanks. Would you explane why the xaml way causes the problem? If you create a complex UserControl having hundreds elements and many depths of layers, it will be too hard to handle those complexes without a xaml. Isn't there a way to use xaml?

Comment: Using XAML creates its own namespace.
But particular element cannot belong to two namespaces.

For complex elements - take an example from default elements.
Please note that there is no padding in XAML.
XAML is used to create the template.
Templates can be very complex.

Template specificity - their namespace does not conflict with the namespace where the template is applied.

Comment: Pardon me. So, you can use XAML to create a UseControl by using Style Templetes?

Comment: I wrote the previous message incorrectly.
I tried several options, including a template.
If XAML is used, an error occurs in any case.

How to solve this - I could not find.

Comment: Right. Thank you for all your sharings.

Answer (score -1):

I made the mistake I wrote about above.
I installed the template in XAML created by Studio. When you add a user control, it creates code from two files: XAML and a partial class in Code-Benind.

For default elements, the implementation is different.
A separate class in C # with properties and a separate XAML theme with a template for this class.
See how custom elements are implemented.

Having done this, I got a working code.
To simplify the example, I did not set a theme, but created a default style in the window resources.

C# for UserControl

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace TrainingWpf1
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Children))]
    public class PropertyPanel : UserControl
    {
        public PropertyPanel()
        {
            Children = new ObservableCollection<UIElement>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<UIElement> Children
        {
            get => (ObservableCollection<UIElement>)GetValue(ChildrenProperty.DependencyProperty);
            private set => SetValue(ChildrenProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ChildrenProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
                nameof(Children),
                typeof(ObservableCollection<UIElement>),
                typeof(PropertyPanel),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }

}
```

XAML for Window

```
<Window x:Class="TrainingWpf1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TrainingWpf1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PropertyPanel}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Title"/>
                            <Border Padding="10" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="6" Background="CadetBlue">
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:PropertyPanel}}}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <DockPanel/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </Border>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <local:PropertyPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ThisProduceAnError" Text="Hello"/>
        </local:PropertyPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```