# Give Name to Control inside a Object Dependency Property of an UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have an UserControl that have Object Propdp:

```
 public partial class HeaderControl : UserControl
    {
        public HeaderControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           DataContext = this;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlContentProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ControlContent), typeof(object), 
               typeof(HeaderControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public object ControlContent
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ControlContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ControlContentProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

In Xaml file:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
     <ContentControl Content="{Binding ControlContent, ElementName=root}"/>
</Grid>
```

if i use it without give a Name to the Button inside it works:

```
 <ctrl:HeaderContorl >
    <ctrl:HeaderContorl.ControlContent>
                <Button Content="Hallooo" FontSize="40"
                         Foreground="Black" Height="100"/>
    </ctrl:HeaderContorl.ControlContent>
 </ctrl:HeaderContorl>
```

But if i name the Button inside it not works:

```
 <ctrl:HeaderContorl >
    <ctrl:HeaderContorl.ControlContent>
                <Button x:Name="Btn" Content="Hallooo" FontSize="40"
                         Foreground="Black" Height="100"/>
    </ctrl:HeaderContorl.ControlContent>
 </ctrl:HeaderContorl>
```

Can someone please tell me why I can't name the button inside?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know that there already is [HeaderedContentControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), which you could use as base class of a custom control?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a WPF UserControl with NAMED content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751325/how-to-create-a-wpf-usercontrol-with-named-content)

Comment: Hi, i can not use HeaderedContentControl or ControlTemplate for what i need. i want to add the Control inside my  HeaderContorl.ControlContent like i want. I just have problem to name the Controls inside it. And i just ask for help why i can´t name the Controls inside the Object dependency property ControlContent of the HeaderControl. thanks